# Changing interpolation steps in path function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using the patch command in matlab to create filled polygons as described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html). The `interp` option interpolate colors (bi-linearly) across polygon faces by specifying a color at each polygon vertex.

```
vertices = [0 0; 0 5; 5 0; 3 3; 3 6; 6 3];
faces = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
C = [5; 1; 4; 3; 2; 6];

p = patch('Faces',faces,'Vertices',vertices,'FaceVertexCData',C, 'FaceColor', 'interp');
colorbar
```

[image]

I was wondering if there is any way so that I can change the interpolation steps in the `patch` command. For example if steps=3, interpolation from color1 to color2 takes 3 steps. When I increase the steps to like 100 then I see a smooth transition between two colors (similar to the default behavior of 'interp' option).

Comment: No, there is no default way of doing it.